# Binding redirection

Tags: c#, dependencies

I have lots of components, and many times one component depends on another. In .Net, if you make change to any assembly, you should change its assembly version to reflect this change. However, this provokes a ripple effect down the dependency chain.

One way of dealing with this is by using binding redirection, mostly if you know that no breaking changes were introduced.

My question is - how frowned upon is the use of binding redirection? Should I always make sure to have none of it when a product is released to production?

EDIT - applications are various services based on a common framework. We are the sole developers and supporters of these services. There is no hotfixing, just pushing new MSI's when necessary.

Comment: What type of application are we talking about? Who is supporting the application? What is your method of pushing hotfixes/service packs etc?

Comment: I don't think it's frowned on. In cases its a necessary evil. [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org) for example will automatically introduce [binding redirects](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-3-unification-via.html) in some cases when trying to resolve versioning issues.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that NuGet does that. So.. it is not considered "half baked" because there are redirects?

Answer (score 1):

If you put more flexible version check on your components, they wouldn't break on minor version change. (http://semver.org/)

The examples are

```
<!-- Accepts any version 6.1 and above -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="6.1" />

<!-- Accepts any version above, but not include 4.1.3. This might be
      used to guarantee a dependency with a specific bug fix. -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="(4.1.3,)" />

<!-- Accepts any version up below 5.x, which might be used to prevent
      pulling in a later version of a dependency that changed its interface.
      However, this form is not recommended because it can be difficult to
      determine the lowest version.  -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="(,5.0)" />

<!-- Accepts any 1.x or 2.x version, but no 0.x or 3.x and higher versions -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="[1,3)" />

<!-- Accepts 1.3.2 up to 1.4.x, but not 1.5 and higher. -
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="[1.3.2,1.5)" />
```

from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/dependency-versions

So, if your package can accepts any version x.x and above, a minor version change wouldn't affect your solution.